# Cannot install mean-cli via npm on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, mean.io

Mean-cli is a package used to initialize meanio full stack javascript framework. But I cannot install it globally via npm. This is what I can provide you to understand what I mean.

```
C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g mean-cli
npm WARN engine mean-cli@0.9.14: wanted: {"node":"0.10.x","npm":"2.1.x"} (current:{"node":"0.10.34","npm":"1.4.28"})

> mean-cli@0.9.14 preinstall C:\Users\Rahul's\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mean-cli
> node ./scripts/preinstall


npm ERR! mean-cli@0.9.14 preinstall: `node ./scripts/preinstall`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mean-cli@0.9.14 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mean-cli package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./scripts/preinstall
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mean-cli
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program     
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "mean-cli"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Windows\System32
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.34
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g npm
C:\Users\Rahul's\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm -> C:\Users\Rahul's\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
npm@2.1.14 C:\Users\Rahul's\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm

C:\Windows\System32>npm -v
2.1.14

C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g mean-cli

> mean-cli@0.9.14 preinstall C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\mean-cli
> node ./scripts/preinstall

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "node" "C:\\Users\\Rahul's\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "mean-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.10.34
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.14
npm ERR! file cmd
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! mean-cli@0.9.14 preinstall: `node ./scripts/preinstall`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mean-cli@0.9.14 preinstall script 'node ./scripts/preinstall'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mean-cli package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./scripts/preinstall
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mean-cli
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\System32\npm-debug.log

C:\Windows\System32>node -v
v0.10.34

C:\Windows\System32>npm -v
2.1.14
```

I have referred a stack overflow question where it was discussed that the node should be updated. My nodejs is updated and I have updated npm as you guys can see. But then I get .scripts/preinstall.js error. Saw their github ticket where they say that this issue has been resolved but still i am facing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I'm havng exact problem

Comment: @codePlusPlus Unfortunately no. I installed virtual box and started using Ubuntu instead on which things were quite smooth. I'd recommend you to update bower and gulp globally and locally. Update npm and node. Please check whether you have installed the necessary microsoft visual c++ redistributable as well for windows.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue.

Running the console as Administrator fixed the issue for me.